# Wrapping text in a cell in a table

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap

Consider the following table

```
\begin{table} 
\centering  
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{1cm}|}
    \hline       
     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (aaaaaa)   &  \url{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}           &    88\%   \\
    \hline       
     \multirow{4}{*}{ccccccccccc (ccccccc)} &  \url{dddddddddddddd} &    50\%   \\
                                                        &  \url{eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}            &    18 \%   \\ 
                                                        &  \url{ffffffffffffff}                 &    11 \%   \\ 
                                                        &  \url{gggggggggggggggggg}             &    7 \%   \\                  
    \hline       
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see in the picture, `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (aaaaaa)` has been wrapped to the next next line within the cell. However, `ccccccccccc (ccccccc)` hasn't been wrapped. How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `multirow` manual:

> `〈width〉` is the width to which the text is to be set. Special values are `*` to indicate that the text parameter’s natural width is to be used, and `=` to indicate that the specified width of the column in which the `\multirowentry` is set should be used.

So, replace `\multirow{4}{*}{ccccccccccc (ccccccc)}` by `\multirow{4}{=}{ccccccccccc (ccccccc)}`.